# Quantify measure of oscillation and amplitude in time-series data

Tags: time-series

Let's define a term, `score`, as a metric that measures the extent of oscillation by incorporating information about amplitude and frequency. High score means that big oscillations happen frequently. Low score means that small oscillations happen intermittently.

[image]

Compare Set 1 and Set 2. They have the same amplitude, but has different frequency, making set 1 to have lower `score=2.1` then set 2 `score=4`.

I want to come up with a metric that allows me to quantify the `score`. I was thinking of taking derivatives, sum them up, and divide by the total number of points:

[image]

But I don't think this is going to work because the absolute difference amplitudes of two points depends on when I sampled them. Furthermore, my data has uneven sampling rate, which makes $\Delta t_i$ non-uniform.

How should I do?

Answer (score 2):

you could perform linear regression using sinusoidal basis functions and then extract the coefficients as estimates of the score. Basically perform a multi-linear regression where your dependent variables are sine waves at various frequencies. The model could look something like this.

$y_t = \beta_0 + \sum_{frq=0}^n \beta_{frq} \cdot f_{frq}(t)$

where $f_{frq}(t) = sin(2\pi \cdot frq \cdot t) $

the size of coefficients $\beta$ could then be used to approximate the score you are interested in. This approach also overcomes the irregular sampling as you only need to evaluate each sine wave at the points where you have data.

Comment: Good Idea but this method is suitable for waves that have the same frequency. How can get score fit the amplitudes and the frequency?